# yourkit on high resolution screen

Tags: java, yourkit

I have a 3200x1800 laptop screen and for most X applications to be usable I need to have

```
Xft.dpi: 192
```

in my `.Xresources` (I use ArchLinux).

But yourkit (and Java in general, I guess) doesn't pick up on these settings. Is there a way to run YourKit with high resolution screen support?